# How to fix an error when using R to do MANOVA

Tags: r, manova

I'm trying to run a MANOVA. everything is running fine until I try to run the next line:

```
mod1<- manova(Y ~ group, data = F0.man)
```

The error I'm getting, regerdless of whatever solution I try, is

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(89L, 45L, 72L, 63L, 86L,  :    replacement has 110 rows, data has 22
```

My data have only 7 columns and 22 rows...
I'll really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post the previous part of the code?

Comment: You can use `dput` to provide example of your data.